# Scheme Function to reverse elements of list of 2-list

Tags: lisp, scheme

This is an exercise from EOPL.
Procedure (invert lst) takes lst which is a list of 2-lists and returns a list with each 2-list reversed.

```
(define invert
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond((null? lst )
         '())
       ((= 2 (rtn-len (car lst)))
        ( cons(swap-elem (car lst))
               (invert (cdr lst))))
       ("List is not a 2-List"))))

;; Auxiliry Procedure swap-elements of 2 element list

(define swap-elem
  (lambda (lst)
    (cons (car (cdr lst))
          (car lst))))

;; returns lengh of the list by calling
(define rtn-len
  (lambda (lst)
    (calc-len lst 0)))        

;; calculate length of the list
(define calc-len
  (lambda (lst n)
    (if (null? lst)
        n
        (calc-len (cdr lst) (+ n 1)))))
```

This seems to work however looks very verbose. Can this be shortened or written in more elegant way ?
How I can halt the processing in any of the individual element is not a 2-list?
At the moment execution proceed to next member and replacing current member with  "List is not a 2-List" if current member is not a 2-list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EOPL language provides the `eopl:error` procedure to exit early with an error message. It is introduced on page 15 of the book (3rd ed.).

The EOPL language does also include the `map` procedure from standard Scheme. Though it may not be used in the book, you can still use it to get a much shorter solution than one with explicit recursion. Also you can use Scheme's standard `length` procedure.

```
#lang eopl

(define invert
  (lambda (lst)
    (map swap-elem lst)))

;; Auxiliary Procedure swap-elements of 2 element list

(define swap-elem
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (= 2 (length lst))
        (list (cadr lst)
              (car lst))
        (eopl:error 'swap-elem
                    "List ~s is not a 2-List~%" lst))))
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that your version of invert actually returns a list of different topology. If you execute `(invert ...)` on `'((1 2) (3 4))`, you'll get back `'((2 . 1) (4 . 3))`, which is a list of conses, not of lists.

I wrote a version of invert that maintains list topology, but it is not tail-recursive so it will end up maintaining a call stack while it's recursing.

```
(define (invert lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      lst
      (cons (list (cadar lst) (caar lst))
            (invert (cdr lst)))))
```

If you want a version that mimics your invert behavior, replace `list` with `cons` in second to last line.

Comment: Thanks a ton. How do I handle list and exit the procedure of individual element is not a 2-list. Your procedure simply skips extra elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to exit early on failure, try call/cc.

```
(call-with-current-continuation
  (lambda (exit)
    (for-each (lambda (x)
                (if (negative? x)
                    (exit x)))
              '(54 0 37 -3 245 19))
    #t))  
                          ===>  -3
```

(Taken from http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_566)

What `call-with-current-continuation` (or `call/cc`, for short) does is pass the point where the function was called in into the function, which provides a way to have something analogous to a return statement in C.  It can also do much more, as you can store continuations, or pass more than one into a function, with a different one being called for success and for failure.

Comment: thanks a lot. Although this is beyond my comprehension level at the moment.:)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse list containing any number or order of sub-lists inside.

```
(define (reverse! lst)
  (if (null? lst) lst
    (if (list? (car lst))
      (append (reverse! (cdr lst)) (cons (reverse! (car lst)) '()))
      (append (reverse! (cdr lst)) (list (car lst))))))
```